# Is there a way to search partial match in multivalue field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a table quiet like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    family text,
    names text[]
)
```

I can search like this:

```
SELECT family
FROM myTable where names @> array['B0WP04'];
```

But I would like to do:

```
SELECT family
FROM myTable where names @> array['%P0%'];
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `parray_gin` extension https://github.com/theirix/parray_gin

This extension is said to work only up to 9.2 but I just installed and tested it on 9.3 and it works well.

Here is how to install it on ubuntu-like systems :)

```
# install postgresql extension network client and postgresql extension build tools
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
easy_install pgxnclient
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3

# get the extension
pgxn install parray_gin
```

And here is my test

```
-- as a superuser: add the extension to the current database
CREATE EXTENSION parray_gin;

-- as a normal user
CREATE TABLE test (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  names TEXT []
);

INSERT INTO test (names) VALUES
  (ARRAY ['nam1', 'nam2']),
  (ARRAY ['2nam1', '2nam2']),
  (ARRAY ['Hello', 'Woooorld']),
  (ARRAY ['Woooorld', 'Hello']),
  (ARRAY [] :: TEXT []),
  (NULL),
  (ARRAY ['Hello', 'is', 'it', 'me', 'you''re', 'looking', 'for', '?']);

-- double up the rows in test table, with many rows, the index is used
INSERT INTO test (names) (SELECT names FROM test);

SELECT count(*) from test; /*
 count  
--------
 997376
(1 row)
*/
```

Now that we have some test data, it's magic time:

```
-- http://pgxn.org/dist/parray_gin/doc/parray_gin.html
CREATE INDEX names_idx ON test USING GIN (names parray_gin_ops);

--- now it's time for some tests
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE names @> ARRAY ['is']; /*

-- WITHOUT INDEX ON NAMES
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..25667.00 rows=1138 width=49) (actual time=0.021..508.599 rows=51200 loops=1)
   Filter: (names @> '{is}'::text[])
   Rows Removed by Filter: 946176
 Total runtime: 653.879 ms
(4 rows)

-- WITH INDEX ON NAMES
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=455.73..3463.37 rows=997 width=49) (actual time=14.327..240.365 rows=51200 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (names @> '{is}'::text[])
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on names_idx  (cost=0.00..455.48 rows=997 width=0) (actual time=12.241..12.241 rows=51200 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (names @> '{is}'::text[])
 Total runtime: 341.750 ms
(5 rows)

*/

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE names @@> ARRAY ['%nam%']; /*

-- WITHOUT INDEX ON NAMES
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..23914.20 rows=997 width=49) (actual time=0.023..590.093 rows=102400 loops=1)
   Filter: (names @@> '{%nam%}'::text[])
   Rows Removed by Filter: 894976
 Total runtime: 796.636 ms
(4 rows)

-- WITH INDEX ON NAMES
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=159.73..3167.37 rows=997 width=49) (actual time=20.164..293.942 rows=102400 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (names @@> '{%nam%}'::text[])
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on names_idx  (cost=0.00..159.48 rows=997 width=0) (actual time=18.539..18.539 rows=102400 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (names @@> '{%nam%}'::text[])
 Total runtime: 490.060 ms
(5 rows)

*/
```

The final performance totally depend on your data and queries but on my dummy example, this extension is very efficient cut query time in half.

Comment: This works really great! However, sometimes the query with index returns no results. Basically for a query using '%a%' which normally returns the entire table now returns 0 row since I created the index.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a bit on Radek's answer, I tried

```
select family
from myTable where 
exists (select 1 from unnest(names) as name where name like '%P0%');
```

and it also works. I searched in the PostgreSQL docs for the `un()` function, but can't find anything.

I'm not saying it doesn't do anything, but I'm just curious about what the `un()` function should do (and happy to have my problem solved)

Comment: `as un(name)` is just fancy aliasing ;). More info: "Another form of table aliasing gives temporary names to the columns of the table, as well as the table itself: `FROM table_reference [AS] alias ( column1 [, column2 [, ...]] )` at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html

Comment: Change `select 1` to `select *` and it does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

In postgreSQL 9.3 you can:

```
select family
from myTable 
join lateral unnest(mytable.names) as un(name) on true
where un.name like '%P0%';
```

But keep in mind that it can produce duplicates so perhaphs you'd like to add distinct.

For earlier versions:

```
select family
from myTable where 
exists (select 1 from unnest(names) as un(name) where un.name like '%P0%');
```